# Views - context filter by nid

Tags: views

I have created a view, which basically queries files of type image. That view creates a block, which associated with a certain content type. So the block is displayed whenever one of the nodes of that type is displayed, exactly what I would like to have.

Each of the files displayed has an entity reference field, which contains multiple references to that content type. So that is a one to many relationship, where one image can have multiple nodes of that type associated.

Is it possible within the views ui, to set a contextual filter that it sorts out each file, whose entity reference field (to that content type) contains the current node id?

In pseudo SQL the statement should look like:

`SELECT filename, path, node_refs FROM files WHERE node_refs contains <current node id>;`

Thanks in Ahead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a relationship as `Entity Reference: Referencing entity`
2. Name it with the name of your content type for instance (easier to read in the view settings)
3. Check the `Require this relationship` option
4. Add a contextual filter with `Content: Nid`

*Here comes the trick!*

5. Choose `Provide default value` in the *WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT IN THE URL* fieldset
6. Type should be `Content ID from URL`

This will make Drupal fetch the context from the current URL where your block is displayed and loop through the files referenced by the current node.

TA-DAAA :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that trick did the trick and was the missing part!